# Date conversion issue in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

There is a column `TriggerDate` of type `varchar(50)`. It stores values in `MM/dd/yyyy` format(eg: 05/21/2016).

There are 10 records in this table for the date May 21, 2016

When I run this query

```
select * 
from Analytics 
where convert(date, TriggerDate) = '2016-05-21'
```

I get the result in the results tab, but the messages tab displays this error

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

However, when I run

```
select top 10 * 
from Analytics 
where convert(date, TriggerDate) = '2016-05-21'
```

there are no errors

Executing `select CONVERT(date,'05/21/2016')` returns `2016-05-21` with no errors.

What baffles me is: how is top 10 making the difference and, it is working on my staging server also running SQL Server 2014.

How should I resolve this?

Using SQL Server 2014 in Windows Server 2012 R2 and the System Date is in the format 5/21/2016

Comment: there are some rows with invalid date format. That's why you should not use varchar to store date value

Comment: I have updated my Q with a new observation. There is no way to change the datatype now. It's a huge table. Any idea how I can find out that culprit rows.

Comment: use `ISDATE()` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx

Comment: @Squirrel. Your guess was bang on. Few records had incorrect date format. Changing them solved the issue. Thank you.

Comment: for better performance, don't convert the value in your column to date. Instead, pass in the date in the same format. `WHERE TriggerDate = '05/21/2016'`

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server convert string to date

```
SELECT convert(datetime, '10/23/2016', 101) -- mm/dd/yyyy
SELECT convert(datetime, '2016.10.23', 102) -- yyyy.mm.dd ANSI date with century
SELECT convert(datetime, '23/10/2016', 103) -- dd/mm/yyyy
SELECT convert(datetime, '23.10.2016', 104) -- dd.mm.yyyy
SELECT convert(datetime, '23-10-2016', 105) -- dd-mm-yyyy
```

Try This

Answer (score 0):

Use below query may be it helps you.

```
select * 
from Analytics 
where convert(varchar(10), cast(TriggerDate as date), 102) = '2016.05.21'
```